# updating a microsoft access record using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to update this record for almost 3 days by now, been round all the Internet and can't find anything that helps me, tried all the solutions but nothing.

I want to update a record, the form is called `search form`, table consists of 8 columns where `student_id` is an *autonumber* so I didn't mess up with it.

This is the last that I came up with and it's still not working, it highlights the `executenonquery()` and gives an error message after pressing the button, that says `no values where given to one or more required parameters` ...

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Anton\Desktop\LoginDatabase\Users.mdb")
        con.Open()
       sql = "update salary set [empname]=?,[department]=?,[date1]=?, [accname]= ?,[accnumber]=?,[backname]=?,[rate]=?,[house]=?,[electricity]=?,[travel]=?, [hardship]= ?,[health]=?,[nhif]=?,[nssf]=?,[insurence]=?,[loan]=?,[welfare]=? where empno = ?"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", TextBox3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", DateTimePicker1.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accname", TextBox4.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accnumber", TextBox5.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bankname", TextBox6.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", TextBox7.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@house", TextBox8.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@electricity", TextBox9.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@travel", TextBox10.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hardship", TextBox11.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@health", TextBox12.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nhif", TextBox13.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nssf", TextBox14.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insurence", TextBox15.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loan", TextBox16.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@welfare", TextBox17.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", TextBox1.Text)
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        MsgBox("updated")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Take out each value one at a time, it'll tell you which one(s) are the problem, which should help point you toward a solution. e.g. remove empName from the update query, and remove it from the parameters. Does it still break? now remove department too, if it still breaks remove date1 etc until you get it working. Now start adding the others back in until you isolate the problem fields.

Answer (score 1):

**Your bug is that you misspelled BankName in the SQL statement.
use " [bankname]=? ".**

### Don't forget that the ExecuteNonQuery method returns an integer telling you how many records were affected.  If the ID isn't found in the table, it won't update, and it won't error, so a messagebox stating "updated" is not always true.

However, it is FAR easier to replace your form and use the native functions of Visual Studio, as follows:

1. Open the **Server Explorer**, click **Connect to a Database** and connect to your MDB file.
2. From the menu, choose **Data > Show Data Sources**.  Click the **Add new Data Source** button.
3. From the Data Sources pane, use **Add New Datasource**, pick Database then Dataset, finish the wizard and choose the Salary table.  A dataset will be created and placed into your project, and you will see it in your Data Sources pane.
4. Without closing the Data Sources pane, Create a new blank form, and it will open in design view.
5. Click the table name "salary" node, and drop down the combo-box to choose **Details**.
6. Expand the table and drop down the date1 column in the same manner to make sure that the **DateTimePicker** control is used.
7. Drag the Salary table from the **Data Sources** pane onto your new blank form.

A form with a navigation bar will appear before your eyes.  A new DataSet by the name of your database will be created.

This will be a MUCH more intuitive form for former MS Access users, and you don't need to create any Insert statements manually, as in your question above.