# Why is my vb code not updating the ms access database (only cached temporarly)

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I am doing a small system using Ms. Access (the database has more than 10 tables ) connecting to visual studio. I made a public class for opening the connection to the database so I can use it in every form. Everything is working and I can get the data from the database But any inserting or deleting data in forms, the database in ms access not getting the update. I can see the new records in forms but nothing in the database.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class dbconnectClass1


'create db connection
Private DBcon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=dental_clinic.accdb;")
'prepare db command
Private dbcmd As OleDbCommand
' db data
Public DBDA As OleDbDataAdapter
Public DBDT As DataTable
'query parameters
Public params As New List(Of OleDbParameter)


'query statics
Public recordcount As Integer
Public Exception As String





Public Sub ExecQuery(query As String)
    'reset query status
    recordcount = 0
    Exception = ""

    Try
        'open connection
        DBcon.Open()
        'create db command
        dbcmd = New OleDbCommand(query, DBcon)
        'load params into dbcommand
        params.ForEach(Sub(p) dbcmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        'clear params list
        params.Clear()
        'excute command and fill dataset
        DBDT = New DataTable
        DBDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(dbcmd)
        recordcount = DBDA.Fill(DBDT)



    Catch ex As Exception
        Exception = ex.Message
    End Try
    'close the database connection
    If DBcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then DBcon.Close()

End Sub
'include query and command parameters
Public Sub addparam(name As String, value As Object)
    Dim newparam As New OleDbParameter(name, value)
    params.Add(newparam)

End Sub
End Class
```

This my code inside the forms:

```
Public Class NewExpense

Private access As New dbconnectClass1
' a varuble having the appointment Id to connect between 2 forms
Private appointmentNo As Integer
Private Function NoError(Optional report As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(access.Exception) Then
        If report = True Then MsgBox(access.Exception)
        Return False
    Else
        Return True

    End If

End Function
Private Sub Savebuttum_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Savebuttum.Click

    Dim oDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value)
    access.addparam("@expensenme", expensenmtXT.Text)
    access.addparam("@expensedetail", ExpenseDetailTXT.Text)
    access.addparam("@expenseamount", ExpenseAmountTXT.Text)
    access.addparam("@expensedate", oDate)
    access.addparam("@expensepaidTo", paidtoTXT.Text)
    access.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO Expense (Expenses_name, expense_details, 
    expenses_amount, ExpenseDate_Paid, ExpensePaid_To) Values (@expensenme, 
    @expensedetail, @expenseamount, @expensedate, @expensepaidTo);")
    'report on errors
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(access.Exception) Then 
    MsgBox(access.Exception) : Exit Sub
    'success



    access.DBDA.Update(access.DBDT)
    MsgBox("Expense Has been Added Successfully")

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Edit question to show output of debug. Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029061/updating-a-microsoft-access-record-using-vb-net and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808528/inserting-data-from-vb-net-to-ms-access-syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement

Comment: `Fill` retrieves data from the database into a `DataTable`. `Update` saves changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.

Answer (score 4):

You have this:

```
params.ForEach(Sub(p) dbcmd.Parameters.Add(p))
```

Great, we add the parameters - looks good to go!

then, next line CLEARS all the work above! (the parameters are removed).

```
    'clear params list
    params.Clear()
```

Next up? Many will build a connection object, then a reader, and then a adaptor. But you ONLY need a data adaptor if you going to update a data table. If you just going to execute a command, then you don't need the data table, and you don't need a adaptor FOR that table. Adaptor = ability to modify a existing datatable (or dataset).

You are MUCH better to use the command object.

Why? Because the command object has a connection object (don't need a separate one).

Because the command object has a data reader for you (no need for a whole data adaptor to JUST fill a table. And remember, you don't need a whole data adaptor UNLESS you are going to send/update a data table back to the database.

And because the command object has the command text, then you don't even need a variable for that!!!

And because all objects are in "one object", then really all you need is something to handy get you the connection.

For your insert example, we really don't gain by having that object, do we?

OK, so here is your insert code without using those extra objects:

In the following, I declare ONE variable, - the SQL command object.

And do the insert.

Incidentally, your save button is not a save - but a insert button - every time you hit it, you will insert a new row. Lets deal with that issue in a bit.

So, here is our code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Expense 
        (Expenses_name, expense_details,expenses_amount, ExpenseDate_Paid, ExpensePaid_To) 
        Values (@expensenme,@expensedetail, @expenseamount, @expensedate, @expensepaidTo)",
            New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TESTOLEDB))

        With cmdSQL.Parameters
            .Add("@expensenme", OleDbType.WChar).Value = expensenmtXT.Text
            .Add("@expensedetail", OleDbType.WChar).Value = ExpenseDetailTXT.Text
            .Add("@expenseamount", OleDbType.Currency).Value = ExpenseAmountTXT.Text
            .Add("@expensedate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
            .Add("@expensepaidTo", OleDbType.WChar).Value = paidtoTXT.Text
        End With

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
```

So things in above:

We have strong data typing and conversion. Because of this, note how I did NOT have to create a separate date/time variable here.

Note the SAME for "money" or so-called currency conversion - again strong data type by using parameters this way.

And is this a date only, or a date+time value? If it is date, then

```
 .Add("@expensedate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
```

If it was/is a date+time, then this:

```
.Add("@expensedate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
```

So, notice how all your object stuff REALLY did not help one bit, and in fact you did not really save code, and above actually had LESS variables defined to do the whole job.

Now, back to the insert issue/problem. (you save is doing a insert). But what about editing existing records?

So, I would suggest you work out the problem this way:

You create/get/have/assume a data row for the form.

The form takes the data row, fills the controls. You edit, and when you hit save, the data row is sent back to the database. So, once this works, then to add? Well, the add code will CREATE a new data row, save to database and THEN you send that new data row to the above existing form that can edit a data row, and can save a data row. So the form now is able to deal with both issues (adding vs editing existing). If the user don't want the row, then you offer a delete button.

And REALLY nice is a data row means you don't deal with SQL, and don't deal with parameters!

So the code (design pattern) I use is thus this:

```
dim da as oledbDataAdaptor
dim myTable as DataTable = MyRstEdit("SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID = " & lngID,da)

dim MyDataRow as DataRow = myTable.Rows(0)

' code to fill controls
txtHotelName.Text = MyDataRow("HotelName")
txtCity.Text = MyDataRow("City")
' etc. etc. etc.
```

Now to save? Well I put the values back into that DataRow like this:

```
MyDataRow("HotelName") = txtHotelName.Text
MyDataRow("City") = txtCity.Text
MyDateRow("BookingDate") = txtTimePick1.Value

da.Update(MyTable)
```

Notice how I don't have parameters, and even strong data type checking occurs for say the above Date/Time booking date column.

And the above is nice, since I don't have to deal with ANY parameters to update a row of data.

The MyRstEdit routine looks like this and returns ByRef a "da" (data adaptor).

```
Public Function MyrstEdit(strSQL As String, Optional strCon As String = "", Optional ByRef oReader As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing) As DataTable

    ' Myrstc.Rows(0)
    ' this also allows one to pass custom connection string - if not passed, then default
    ' same as MyRst, but allows one to "edit" the recordset, and add to recordset and then commit the update.

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = GetConstr()
    End If

    Dim mycon As New SqlConnection(strCon)

    oReader = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, mycon)
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Dim cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(oReader)

    Try
        oReader.Fill(rstData)
        oReader.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = True
    Catch
    End Try
    Return rstData


End Function
```

So, now in vb.net, I actually find it is LESS code then even writing + using recordsets in MS-Access VBA code.

However, BEFORE you go down ANY of the above road?

Have you considered using the vb.net data binding features. Data-binding in vb.net means that you do NOT write ANY of the above code. it means that vb.net will do all of the dirty work, and write and setup ALL OF the code for you to edit data on a form. The end result is you don't write any code to update a table.

You do have to use + create a "data set". Once done, then you just drag controls onto the form, and you even get this. So you just drop in a dataset, table adaptor, Binding navigator, and you get this:

[image]

Note now the tool bar at the top (and you can place it on the bottom if you wish). So you get this:

[image]

So that WHOLE form was created without having to write ONE line of code. And you can see we have navigation, edits and saves and even the ability to add. So, you can build up a editing form - and it thus becomes similar to say working in MS-Access and ZERO lines of code is required to build the above form.

However, if you ARE going to roll your own code? Then use a data row. That way you can shuffle data to/from the table, and NOT have to use parameters and SQL update and insert statements - but ONLY have nice clean code in which you shove, or get values from that data row. .Net will "write" all the update stuff for you.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! So, something like `Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Some sql command string", New SqlConnection("My connection string"))` will take care of closing and disposing the connection? I tried to drill down on the Command.Dispose but I go lost.

Comment: yes - it cleans up and closes everything.  Prior to the using block, then you would in most cases would use object.Dispose() or cmdSQL.Dispose() etc. - but using takes care of that issue.